# Variable Selection Methods

Tags: feature-selection

In many descriptions of variable selection, we are **given** the number of variables in advance and have to choose the variables according to some method. For example, in forward selection, we are given the null model and potential $p$ variables in advance and choose the best model with one additional variable added (according to highest $R^2$ or least $RSS$) to the previous model and then choose the best amongst the $p$ models according to AIC, BIC, etc.

But how do we initially choose the $p$ variables? Through intuition and subject matter expertise?

Comment: In the last sentence of the first paragraph, I believe you mean $p$ variables.

Comment: @LucasFarias: No I meant $p$ models. For example, in forward selection, you start with the null model $M_0$ with just the intercept. Then you consider all $p$ models with one variable added to $M_0$ and select the best one and call it $M_1$ etc.. until $M_p$. So you have $p$ models and you choose the best one according to AIC, BIC, adjusted $R^2$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's exactly how it is done.

But be carefl about all those automatic methods.

Comment: In which sense should he be careful?

Comment: @LucasFarias there is a ton of literature showing that these methods (eg forward stepwise) pick the real x variables very poorly and often pick a great deal of noise (not really related to outcome). So this is at least ONE aspect of peter flom’s answer.

Comment: In addition, the parameter estimates will be biased away from 0, the p values will be too small, the standard errors will be too small and the models too complex.  Furthermore, the resulting model may make no sense. In addition, it ignores the fat that non-significant variables can be very important.